# Using ClassTag to see if what I have is the same as the template type

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write a templated function that retrieves a value from a `Map` based on type. If the template type doesn't match the type in the `Map`, it should return `None`:

```
val validMetadata: Map[String, Any] = Map(
  "string" -> "this is a string",
  "int" -> 12,
  "double" -> 12.12
)

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
private def getMetadata[T](key: String)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Option[T] =
  validMetadata.get(key) match {
    case Some(scalar) if scalar.getClass == tag.tpe => Option(scalar)
    case _ => None
  }

getMetadata[Int]("int") // should return Option(12)
getMetadata[Int]("string") // should return None
```

This doesn't work and neither does any other of the hundreds of variations I've tried. Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Yes. Updated the original question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing the definition of classes and types. `getClass` returns class meta data. A `TypeTag` contains type meta data. They are different things. For example, `String`, `List`, `Map` are classes, but `List[Int]` and `Map[Int, String]` are types. Comparing a class to a type in general doesn't make sense, because you might be comparing something like `List` to a `List[Int]`, for example.

You can make it work using `ClassTag`, and it's extractor:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

val validMetadata: Map[String, Any] = Map(
  "string" -> "this is a string",
  "int" -> 12,
  "double" -> 12.12
)

def getMetadata[T](key: String)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): Option[T] =
  validMetadata.get(key) match {
    case Some(tag(scalar)) => Option(scalar)
    case _ => None
  }

scala> getMetadata[Int]("int")
res1: Option[Int] = Some(12)

scala> getMetadata[Int]("string")
res2: Option[Int] = None

scala> getMetadata[String]("string")
res3: Option[String] = Some(this is a string)
```

But this can fail for classes with type parameters. For example if you change the definition of `validMetadata` to:

```
val validMetadata: Map[String, Any] = Map(
  "ints" -> List(1, 2, 3),
  "strings" -> List("a", "b", "c")
)

scala> getMetadata[List[String]]("ints")
res5: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3)) // No!!
```

The type parameter of `List` is erased. `TypeTag` would allow you to hold all of the type information, however, once your data is stored in a `Map[String, Any]`, all of that type information is lost, so `TypeTag` can't help. In order to use it, you would have to fundamentally change your `Map` to something like:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

case class Tagged[A](value: A)(implicit val tag: TypeTag[A])

val validMetadata: Map[String, Tagged[_]] = Map(
  "ints" -> Tagged(List(1, 2, 3)), // Allows us to save type information at compile time, to carry over to run time
  "strings" -> Tagged(List("a", "b", "c"))
)

def getMetadata[T](key: String)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Option[T] =
  validMetadata.get(key) match {
    case Some(tagged) if(tag.tpe =:= tagged.tag.tpe) => Option(tagged.value.asInstanceOf[T])
    case _ => None
  }

scala> getMetadata[List[String]]("ints")
res6: Option[List[String]] = None

scala> getMetadata[List[String]]("strings")
res7: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(a, b, c))
```

This is clunky, but isn't otherwise possible to recover this depth of type information when using an un-typed `Map`. Depending on your requirements, you may want to look into something like [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) `HMap` for type safety.

Comment: Thank you for this amazing description!